# Validating recursive string structure

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a string which represents the serialized form of an expression tree.  Here are some examples that I want to validate:

- Ex 1: `(6+2)`
- Ex 2: `(6*(4+2))`
- Ex 3: `(9*(4-(7*3)))`
- Ex 4: `((5+2)/(9+2))`
- Ex 5: `(((2-1)+2)/(9+()7*2))`

As you can see from Ex 1, the simple case is where I have two numbers with an operation surrounded by parenthesis.  However, either number could also be an expression.  These expressions can be as deep as required.

I am working in .NET and wanted to write a regular expression to validate that the format of the string complies with what I showed in the examples.  I cannot figure out how to write the .NET regular expression to perform this validation.

The simple case can be validated with the following:

```
string testCase = "(6+2)";
string baseExpression = "([(][0-9][+-/*][0-9][)])";
Regex rgx = new Regex(baseExpression );
bool returnValue = rgx.IsMatch(testCase);
```

However, I don't know how to introduce the recursion that a number can be replaced by another baseExpression;

The examples show integers for the numbers.  Ultimately I want to be able to represent these numeric values as floats with (or without) a decimal point.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you need a classic [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree): Regex is not suited (and in most implementation even capable) of *parsing*, only *matching*.

Comment: @Bohemian .NET has special support specifically for this problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was afraid someone was going to say that - recursive regex. I've qualified the "capable" part from my comment, but TBH I think it's still more or less good advice. If someone posts a working solution in regex, I'll be happy to delete my comment

Comment: This comes under context free language.. and regular expressions are not powerful enough to validate them.. I would use [stack implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Bohemian .NET does not have recursive regex, it uses a different hack for the same purpose :)

Comment: Is this ultimately for a calculator, as in in the end you need to evaluate the expression?

Answer (score 1):

In general, regular expression is not powerful enough to validate parentheses in an expression. However, .NET supports [*balancing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html), which can be used to validate your expressions as follows:

```
^[^()]*(?>(?>(?'open'\()[^()]*)+(?>(?'-open'\))[^()]*)+)+(?(open)(?!))$
```

`'open'` and `'-open'` are balancing groups. The working of this expression is explained in the article at the link.

Even though .NET lets you do this in a regex, it is not the best approach to solving this problem, because any regex-based solution becomes a fragile, "write-once-and-never-touch-again" solution. You would be much better off writing a simple [*recursive descent parser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for the task, because the solution that you code in this way would be easy to read and a lot more maintainable.

Comment: To determine correct use of parenthesis within something was one of the first tasks given when I studied computer science. I second the idea of writing some simple code to do this instead of using regex, which is just not the tool designed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not a good tool for parsing tasks. For this specific one, you can use DataTable to evaluate your formula:

```
static bool evaluateFormula(String formula)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var v = dt.Compute(formula, "");//if you need the result return this
        return true;
    }
    catch(SyntaxErrorException)
    {
        return false;
    }            
}
```

In your example, the last formula is invalid, since 9+()7*2 doesn't really makes sense:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(evaluateFormula("(6+2)"));
    Console.WriteLine(evaluateFormula("(6*(4+2))"));
    Console.WriteLine(evaluateFormula("(9*(4-(7*3)))"));
    Console.WriteLine(evaluateFormula("((5+2)/(9+2))"));
    Console.WriteLine(evaluateFormula("(((2-1)+2)/(9+()7*2))"));
}
```

Outputs:

```
True
True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a Stack Structure for stacking up the characters from your string input. 
[System.Collections.Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx)

No need for recursion here. Just putting your characters one at a time in your stack and controlling it how you wish.

ps: i made a verifyXML method in java that might help in some way [VerifyXML Java](http://pastie.org/10240079)